# Python build exe file runs successfully in conda prompt but gets quit while running

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, build, pyinstaller

Here is the code,

```
from pymatting import *
#import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()


def func():
    print( "before matting")
    scale = 1
    print( "1")
    image = load_image(r"s.png", "RGB", scale, "box")
    trimap = load_image(r"tri.png", "GRAY", scale, "nearest")
    print( "2")
    # estimate alpha from image and trimap
    alpha = estimate_alpha_knn(image, trimap)
    
    print( "3")
    # estimate foreground from image and alpha
    foreground = estimate_foreground_ml(image, alpha, return_background=False)
    print( "4")
    # save cutout
    cutout = stack_images(foreground, alpha)
    
    save_image("2_out.png", cutout)   
    print( "saved")
    
button = tk.Button(root, text = "start",command =func) 
button.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

I have build the exe using pyinstaller like

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import six --hidden-import='pkg_resources.py2_warn' --hidden-import pymatting main.py
```

it gets build successfully, and using in conda prompt `./main.exe` I can able to view the output..

But this code keeps failing when main.exe open directly using windows. It exits while doing it.. Program quits without showing any error..

(i think that linear solving equations of numpy functions are not getting included in the build, such as numpy.inner or numpy.linalg  etc. on my anlaysis, sorry if i am wrong)

Suggest me a way to solve this.
this is the original image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3DXh.png) and its trimap [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uh2j.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean *... code keeps failing...*, could you show the error or be more specific about the problem ?

Comment: keeps failing means not working as expected.  the exe file stop and exit the application automatically..

when running in conda prompt I can able to view the output. But running in windows, it just quits the program, no error showing

Comment: If the code works in general but the exe gets quit automatically, then there could be error at some part of the code, take a look at the prompt to see, what the error is? Keep in mind you will have to copy the exe to the project directory too., or else, when you press the button the image path is invalid and hence it will bring an error and crash.

Comment: I have copied the image into build directory and it works fine with conda prompt.. But in general run no error is shown in console.. And just quits

Comment: `pyinstaller --hidden-import numpy --hidden-import six --hidden-import='pkg_resources.py2_warn' --hidden-import pymatting main.py`  try this out?

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is pymatting uses to numpy functions `np.linalg.norm` and `np.inner`, these two caused the real time application to exit. I replaced both the functions with alternatives `scipy.linalg.norm and manual inner function`.  Pyinstaller or cx_freeze will not take these two functions while building the app. So its fails outside the conda prompt environment

Comment: Is the problem fixed? Why does pyinstaller not work with numpy? I have an exe made with `numpy.linalg`. Anyway try out, `pyinstaller --hidden-import numpy --hidden-import six --hidden-import='pkg_resources.py2_warn' --hidden-import pymatting main.py`